# Crash symbolication for iOS Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, crash-reports, dsym

My app has an embedded framework, created in the same project, analysing the crash reports I've noticed that the symbolication for the embedded framework doesn't work:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x23b75856 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x354eadfa objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x23b7b020 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184
3   CoreFoundation                  0x23b78c7a ___forwarding___ + 698
4   CoreFoundation                  0x23aa81a4 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   MyFramework                     0x002d72aa 0x2c9000 + 58026
6   MyFramework                     0x002edd12 0x2c9000 + 150802
7   CoreData                        0x238f0346 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 174
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x35c0fe16 _dispatch_client_callout + 18
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x35c18e82 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 538
10  CoreData                        0x238f0242 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 202
11  MyFramework                     0x002edb50 0x2c9000 + 150352
12  MyFramework                     0x002ed596 0x2c9000 + 148886
13  MyFramework                     0x0030273c 0x2c9000 + 235324
14  MyFramework                     0x002e8c52 0x2c9000 + 130130
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x35c0fe2a _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x35c18840 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 1364
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x35c1b80c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1568
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x35c1b1e6 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 90
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35da4e08 _pthread_wqthread + 1020
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x35da49f8 start_wqthread + 4
```

no problems instead for the main app:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37ee868a objc_retain + 10
1   MyApp                           0x000c4ae8 -[LoginManager startupNeedToDisplayOnBoarding] (LoginManager.m:26)
2   MyApp                           0x000cd6e2 -[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] (AppDelegate.m:65)
3   UIKit                           0x2a715098 -[UIApplication _stopDeactivatingForReason:] + 1080
4   UIKit                           0x2a92d594 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2344
5   UIKit                           0x2a940b54 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3218 + 36
6   UIKit                           0x2a92a7a6 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 134
7   FrontBoardServices              0x2e78cca4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 232
8   FrontBoardServices              0x2e78cf90 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2651c7c6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2651c3b6 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2651a71e __CFRunLoopRun + 806
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2646d0d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2646cecc CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
14  UIKit                           0x2a6fb606 -[UIApplication _run] + 526
15  UIKit                           0x2a6f62dc UIApplicationMain + 144
16  Cinime                          0x000af75e main (main.m:14)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x3861c872 start + 2
```

The issue is obviously in the build settings, but "Debug information format" is already "DWARF with dSYM file" and all the other debug-strip-dsym related settings are identical to the main app.

Even crashlytics isn't able to symbolicate.

---

Framework "strip" configuration

[image]

---

Here the two dSYM files:

Framework:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>English</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.xcode.dsym.com.MyCompanyAAA.MyFramework</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>dSYM</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>0.1.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>3</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

App:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
        <string>English</string>
        <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.xcode.dsym.com.MyCompanyBBB.MyApp</string>
        <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
        <string>6.0</string>
        <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
        <string>dSYM</string>
        <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
        <string>????</string>
        <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
        <string>2.0.0</string>
        <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
        <string>102</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

NOTE CFBundleIdentifier:

Framework: **com.MyCompanyAAA.MyFramework**

App: **com.MyCompanyBBB.MyApp**

Yes the company use two different company id, can it be a problem?

---

dSYM bundle structure:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have the dSYM for the framework and does it have the same UUID for the architecture as the one mentioned in the binary images section of the crash report? Otherwise symbolication is not possible.

Comment: @Kerni question updated, thanks.

Comment: What you listed are not the dSYM files and don't show the UUIDs.

Comment: nope, is the info.plist contained in the dSYM file, the only other file is compiled (nothing to post here) and have the name of the framework (have a look to the image)

Comment: The content of the info.plist is generic. It doesn't contain the UUIDs of the binary and you didn't post the UUID of the frameworks in the crash report. Comparing both will tell you if you have the symbols so symbolication of those stack frames should work.

Comment: you asked me to post the dSYM... where i can find the dSYM UUID?